# Bash Script: tar up folder and email it

Tags: bash, email, cron, tar

I am looking to create a bash script that I can use for a cronjob that will

1. Tar up a folder: tar -czf foldername-TIMESTAMP.tar.gz ~/public_html/foldername
2. Email that as an attachment
3. Delete the tar.gz

I have mail, mailx, rm, and tar commands as needed.

The purpose is basically as a back up of the file system to my email.

Comment: Just one comment, does your mail server support large attachments?

Comment: I'm not sure, however the file sizes should be low. 25MB or below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use this because mutt usually not by default on Centos distribution and mail it's default.

```
FILENAME=foldername-$(date +%Y-%m-%d_%H_%M_%S).tar.gz; \
tar -czf $FILENAME ~/public_html/foldername; \
cat $FILENAME | uuencode binario | mail -s "Backup /public_html/foldername" some@email.you.like; \
rm -f $FILENAME
```

Answer (score 0):

Using mutt you could do it like this:

```
FILENAME=foldername-$(date +%Y-%m-%d_%H_%M_%S).tar.gz
tar -czf $FILENAME ~/public_html/foldername
mutt -s "Some subject" -a $FILENAME some@email.you.like < preformatted_mail.txt
```